# Acurracy doesen't work pytorch (stays at 0)

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch

The accuracy on my code doesn't work(accu), it stays at 0, even though it should get higher.
The loss function works perfectly fine but the accu doesn't and i dont know why it doesnt go up.
It doesn't even show an error or anything it just stays at 0 all the time.
And i need the accu variable to evaluate the trained data with matplotlib.
What did i do wrong in this code?

```
import torch
import os
from torchvision import transforms
from PIL import Image
from os import listdir
import random
import torch.optim as optim
from torch.autograd import Variable
import torch.nn.functional as F
import torch.nn as nn
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from tqdm import tqdm
from torchsummary import summary

normalize = transforms.Normalize(
    mean = [0.485, 0.456, 0.406],
    std = [0.229, 0.224, 0.225])

transform = transforms.Compose([
     transforms.Resize(256),
     transforms.CenterCrop(256),
     transforms.ToTensor(), normalize])

train_data_list = []
target_list = []
train_data = []
waited = False
files = listdir('catsanddogs/train/')
for i in range(len(listdir('catsanddogs/train/'))):
    if len(train_data) == 58 and not waited:
        waited = True
        continue
    f = random.choice(files)
    files.remove(f)
    img = Image.open("catsanddogs/train/" + f)
    img_tensor = transform(img)
    train_data_list.append(img_tensor)
    isSomething = 0
    isCat = 1 if 'cat' in f else 0
    isDog = 1 if 'dog' in f else 0
    if isDog == 0 and isCat == 0:
        isSomething = 2
    target = [isCat, isDog, isSomething] #, isSomthing
    target_list.append(target)
    if len(train_data_list) >= 256:
        train_data.append((torch.stack(train_data_list), target_list))
        train_data_list = []
        target_list = []
        print('Loaded batch ', len(train_data), 'of ', int(len(listdir('catsanddogs/train/')) / 64))
        print('Percentage Done: ', 100 * len(train_data) / int(len(listdir('catsanddogs/train/')) / 64), '%')
        if len(train_data) > 2                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      :
            break

class Netz(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Netz, self).__init__()
        self.conv1 = nn.Conv2d(3, 6, kernel_size=5)
        self.conv2 = nn.Conv2d(6, 12, kernel_size=5)
        self.conv3 = nn.Conv2d(12, 18, kernel_size=5)
        self.conv4 = nn.Conv2d(18, 24, kernel_size=5)
        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(3456, 1000)
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(1000, 3)

    def forward(self, x):
       x = self.conv1(x)
       x = F.max_pool2d(x, 2)
       x = F.relu(x)
       x = self.conv2(x)
       x = F.max_pool2d(x, 2)
       x = F.relu(x)
       x = self.conv3(x)
       x = F.max_pool2d(x, 2)
       x = F.relu(x)
       x = self.conv4(x)
       x = F.max_pool2d(x, 2)
       x = F.relu(x)
       x = x.view(-1, 3456)
       x = F.relu(self.fc1(x))
       x = self.fc2(x)
       return torch.sigmoid(x)

model = Netz()
if os.path.isfile('catdognetz.pt'):
    model = torch.load('catdognetz.pt')

optimizer = optim.SGD(model.parameters(), lr=0.001, momentum=0.9)

def count_parameters(model):
  return sum(p.numel() for p in model.parameters() if p.requires_grad)

count_parameters(model)

train_losses = []
train_accu = []


def train(epoch):
    print('\nEpoch : %d' % epoch)
    model.train()
    running_loss = 0
    correct = 0
    total = 0
    for data, target in tqdm(train_data):
        target = torch.Tensor(target)
        data = Variable(data)
        target = Variable(target)
        inputs, labels = data[0], data[1]
        optimizer.zero_grad()
        out = model(data)
        criterion = F.binary_cross_entropy
        loss = criterion(out, target)
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()

        running_loss += loss.item()
        _, predicted = out.max(1)
        total += target.size(0)
        correct += predicted.eq(labels).sum().item()

    train_loss = running_loss / len(train_data)
    accu = 100. * correct / total

    train_accu.append(accu)
    train_losses.append(train_loss)
    print('Train Loss: %.3f | Accuracy: %.3f' % (train_loss, accu))
```

Comment: What are target and labels variable what are their shapes?? Aren't they supposed to be the same I recommend using `torch.utils.data.DataLoader`

Answer (score 0):

You should delete this row, because I do not think it is true:

```
inputs, labels = data[0], data[1]
```

because you do not need it, where did you use `inputs`? your ground-truth classes or actual classes are `targets`, therefore you should use the same variable to compare to the predicted classes. You should replace `labels` with targets in this line:

```
correct += predicted.eq(targets).sum().item()
```

*Besides all these steps, you should try to print your targets to make sure that you have configured targets correctly and as they should be.*